# How to add menu in drupal?

Tags: php, drupal-7

I am implementing a new website with customized theme. I have added menus(structure-> Add menu) but its displaying only in the default theme.Its not appearing in my theme.How I can show the menu in customized theme

theme: I changed one html file to theme
drupal version 7.22

Comment: You could supply more information, possibly like your Drupal version, The theme name, etc etc etc.

Comment: ok I added all those details thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all menus are blocks and are displayed in regions of page

go to /admin/structure/block and put your menu block in proper region since different themes have different regions

Answer (score 0):

Use ready module it will help to customize menu easily and also allow for multiple level menu

[Nice menu](https://drupal.org/project/nice_menus)

[image]